# Some questions about PBKDF2

Tags: cryptography, passwords, pbkdf2

I'm using PBKDF2 to derive a key from a password string in my app and I just have a few questions about it.

First is I saw lots of PBKDF2 online using hashes like HMAC-SHA256. What does it mean that it uses HMAC-SHA256 and not just HMAC? I thought HMAC encrypts data with a key.

Second, I read that there was BlackBerry vulnerability because its PBKDF2 function only used one iteration (instead of like 1000). Would one iteration be the same as just hashing the password (say with SHA256).

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link regarding the BlackBerry vulnerability?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#BlackBerry_vulnerability

Comment: That alleged vulnerability has less to do with the iteration count, and more to do with the fact that people use weak passwords, and that the BlackBerry backup utility includes a password encrypted database in the backup image. An iteration count of 10000 won't help if the password, for instance, is just a four digit pin code.

Comment: Let's say the password was just made into a key with a MD5 hash. Would rainbow tables be a problem because they make brute forcing a faster process?

Comment: Rainbow tables is a technique used if you got a list of hashed passwords e.g. from a hacked server. It's a different question entirely.

Comment: Oh, so it would be just as secure to hash the password then and I don't need PBKDF2?

Comment: It's not possible to say whether it would be OK to use a hash as KDF without detailed information about your application and how it is used. IOW the answer is that it might be, but if you have to ask, you have probably not analyzed it designed it accordingly, so it is probably better if you use PKCS#5 all the way.

Comment: You may also find this question relevant: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one iteration is the same roughly as calling the underlying hmac function. You don't want to do this, it makes it far easier to compute the function and thus far easier to brute force password choices. More iterations makes the process take longer.

PBKDF2 uses HMAC. HMAC, however, is an algorithm which uses any hash function. You can plug in md5, sha1,sha2, or anything else.

[image: HMAC]

Answer (score 2):

HMAC uses a hash function internally.  It does not encrypt data; it just creates a verifiable "signature" (Message Authentication Code) using a secret key.  HMAC-SHA256 means HMAC using the SHA256 hash function.  You can also have HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-MD5, or HMAC-WhateverHash.

Yes, with one iteration, PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 is a lot like hashing the password with SHA256.  You still have a salt, and the hash function is invoked twice (see any reference on HMAC), but it is nevertheless a lot faster to check lots of passwords.

Comment: Yes and no. An iteration count of 1 vs 1000 is pretty insignificant if the passwords contain enough entropy to begin with. Adding a work factor equivalent to 10 bits of security won't do much, if you need 256 bits of security, and the passwords are all 8 characters 7 bit ASCII.

Comment: @Henrick Hellström: Did you intend your comment to be an answer?

Comment: @PeterO.: I think Nemo gave a correct, good answer. My comment concerned only the phrase "a lot faster".

Comment: So if it's an encrypted email for example, I would HMAC the email address with a key and then the recipient would do so with the same key and check to see if they are the same? And how does HMAC play along with PBKDF2

Comment: PBKDF2 uses a PRF (pseudo random function) internally. Which PRF is used is a configuration option, and HMAC-SHA1 just happens to be the most common (and recommended/default) choice for that PRF.

Comment: How's PBKDF2_HMACSHA1 as opposed to PBKDF2_HMACSHA256? I am creating a key that is 256 bits long but in both cases PBKDF2 hands me a key with the right length..

Comment: @Henrick: You're right that 1000 iterations isn't very much, but with a reasonably good password (say, around 30-40 bits of entropy) it can still make the difference between "trivial to guess" and "this'll take a while". Really, though, the appropriate iteration count for PBKDF2 on a personal device is however many iterations your users are willing to wait for when they log in. Which, on a modern device (even a mobile one) is almost certainly way more than 1000.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: An iteration count of 1000 adds the equivalent of 10 bits of entropy. This is typically less than the difference in entropy between the worst passwords and best passwords, and it is certainly insufficient to get 256 bits of security (which is the encryption strength BlackBerry is using) unless the password already has 246 bits of entropy. But of course there are cases when a high iteration count really does make a difference. I am just not convinced the BlackBerry vulnerability case is one of them.